# Grafana SQL template variables (value, text)

Tags: sql, grafana, presto

I'm using the Grafana Athena plugin for analysing time series data. I want to allow my users to select multiple columns in a drop down and have them displayed in a panel. To do this, I'm using a query as below:

```
SELECT
    $__timeGroup(t, $__interval) as time,
    AVG(${signal:csv}) as ${signal:text}
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    $__timeFilter(t)
GROUP BY
    $__timeGroup(t, $__interval)
```

This works as intended when the dropdown signal value equals only 1 column. However, I would like for the user to be able to return more than 1 column and have the results displayed. I can do this manually via a query as below:

```
SELECT
    $__timeGroup(t, $__interval) as time,
    AVG(col1) as avg_col1,
    AVG(col2) as avg_col2
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    $__timeFilter(t)
GROUP BY
    $__timeGroup(t, $__interval)
```

However, the problem is that I want the user to be able to select between 1 and e.g. up to 10 columns via a dropdown - and then have this be displayed accordingly.

I have a "non-ideal" solution where I create a variable that returns the column names "wrapped" in the required text, i.e. as below:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('AVG(', column_name, ') as avg_', column_name)
FROM 
    information_schema.columns 
WHERE 
    table_schema = '${database:csv}' 
    AND table_name = 'tbl_${device:csv}_${message:csv}'
```

This works, but has the implication that the user is now looking at a dropdown of variables that also include the wrapper text - which is not ideal.

To solve this, I tried the below:

```
SELECT 
    column_name as __text, CONCAT('AVG(', column_name, ') as avg_', column_name) AS __value
FROM 
    information_schema.columns 
WHERE 
    table_schema = '${database:csv}' 
    AND table_name = 'tbl_${device:csv}_${message:csv}'
```

This results in the dropdown looking as intended (showing just the `column_name` texts), but the values are also just equal to the column names when I use my query as below:

```
SELECT
    $__timeGroup(t, $__interval) as time,
    ${signal:csv}
FROM
    tbl_${device}_${message:csv}
WHERE
    $__timeFilter(t)
GROUP BY
    $__timeGroup(t, $__interval)
```

This seems to contrast the guidance in e.g. [this documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/#query-variable) that states that one should be able to use the following:

```
SELECT hostname AS __text, id AS __value FROM my_host
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Also, if there is some alternative way to simply return the column names and instead adjust my panel query to achieve the intended result, I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate aggregation and columns selection: aggregate all columns, and then return only those that needed.

This can be done with sub-query or CTE. Here is example:

```sql
WITH aggregated_data AS (
  SELECT
    $__timeGroup(t, $__interval) as time,
    AVG(col1) as col1,
    AVG(col2) as col2,
    AVG(col3) as col3,
    AVG(col4) as col4,
    AVG(col5) as col5
  FROM  my_table
  WHERE $__timeFilter(t)
  GROUP BY $__timeGroup(t, $__interval)
)
SELECT time, ${signal:csv}
FROM   aggregated_data
```

---

Alternatively, if you have *extremely* large number of columns, and aggregation of all columns is undesirable/unfeasible, and to keep everything tidy, you can keep you variable as is, but create one additional (hidden) variable, that will contain wrapped expressions.

For this you'll need:

1. Add new variable with type *Query*, and your data source selected,
2. set *Show on dashboard* to *Nothing*,
3. set query to

```sql
select 
 array_join(
  transform(
   split('${signal:csv}', ','),
   x -> 'AVG(' || x || ') as AVG_' || x),
 ', ');
```

This way your initial list of columns, like "col1,col2,col3", will be converted into "AVG(col1) as AVG_col1, AVG(col2) as AVG_col2, AVG(col3) as AVG_col3", and can be later used in panel query in a usual way

```sql
SELECT
    $__timeGroup(t, $__interval) as time,
    $my_prepared_columns
FROM  my_table
WHERE $__timeFilter(t)
GROUP BY $__timeGroup(t, $__interval)
```

Comment: Fantastic. I used your suggestion on the additional query logic, but I also added in a REPLACE statement on the x. This in turn allows me to use the SHOW COLUMNS method to return a list of columns in the table (fast and cheap) and use your suggested query to replace the trailing white spaces before parsing these. Great!

Comment: @mfcss, I'm not sure I fully understand what you are saying,  but `trim` is probably better suited for removal of the trailing spaces.